# Problems setting up artifactory as a docker registry

Tags: ssl, docker, artifactory, docker-registry

im currently trying to setup a private Docker Registry in Artifacory (v4.7.4).

I've setup a local,remote and virtual docker Repository, added Apache as a Reverse Proxy. Added a DNS Entry for the virtual "docker" Repo.

Reverse Proxy is working but if i try something like:

```
docker pull docker.my.company.com/ubuntu:16.04
```

I'm getting:

> https://docker.my.company.com/v1/_ping: x509: certificate is valid for
>   *.company.com, company.com, not docker.my.company.com

My Artifactory URL is: "my.company.com/artifactory" and i want the repositorys to be accessible on repo.my.company.com/artifactory.

I also have a Wildcard Certificate for company.com so i don't understand whats the problem here.

Or is there a way to access Artifactory over just http without SSL

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi @Robert, can you share your reverse proxy config if your using nginx? Did you have the server name configured as 'docker.my.company.com'? or did you have a general config for all repos?

Comment: Hi, we dropped the whole artifactory repo thing and are now just using docker.io, because with sub-sub domains for each repo we would have to get wildcard certificates for every repo. On top docker.io is much more simpler than the artifactory config which is some kind of useless in production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [RFC-2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#page-5) Wildcard certificate matches only the one level down domains, but not deeper:

> E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.

In this case what you should do is use ports for mapping repositories, instead of subdomains, so the `docker` repository will be accessible under, for example `my.company.com:5001/` instead of `docker.my.company.com`.

You can find the explanation about the change and how to do it using Artifactory Proxy settings generator in the [User Guide](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy#ConfiguringaReverseProxy-DockerReverseProxySettings).

Comment: Hi @JBaruch, would a multidomain certificate that supports both my.company.com and docker.my.company.com work?

Comment: @user_mda, as I mentioned in the answer the match is done only to the same level, that means that `my.company.com` and `your.company.com` works, but `docker.my.company.com` doesn't.

Comment: Hi @JBaruch, I understand that with a wildcard certificate it will only support same level, but I have a certificate that is multi domain and supports both my.company.com as well as docker.my.company.com The question is would artifactory support such a repository with such a certificate ?

Comment: I am following the example here https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Running+with+Docker, where  the supported domains are art.local and docker-virtual.art.local

Comment: Hi,

Don't know if you still need this, but what we did to have this working is to use the subject alternative name in the certificate. So you have your wildcard certificate matching *.my.company.com with SAN to my.company.com. Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to live with the certificate-name mismatch for-now, and understand the security implications of ignoring the name-mismatch and accessing the repo insecurely, you can apply the following workaround:

- Edit `/etc/default/docker` and add the option `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry docker.my.company.com"`.
- Restart docker: `[sudo] service docker restart`.